# GitLab 5.0: Git push via SSH fails, but no errors with HTTPS or with direct SSH connection

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

When I attempt to git push, I get the usual error

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

However, pushing and pulling works fine via HTTPS.

I figured it would be a problem with the SSH then, but connecting doesn't seem to produce any errors, it accepts my public key, gives me the welcome message and exits with 0.

```
$ ssh -vT git@git.server.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/adam/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.server.com [420.420.555.555] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 96:cc:........
debug1: Host 'git.server.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/adam/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to git.server.com ([257.257.257.257]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
Welcome to GitLab, !
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2512, received 2968 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5567.4, received 6578.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Running this command fails though

```
ssh git@git.server.com "ls /home/git/repositories/adam/my-repo.git"
```

Comment: Which GitLab version are you using?

Comment: @VonC 5.0. It's in the title. To confirm, I've checked out the `5-0-stable` branch

Comment: Sorry for the question, I should have read the title ;) 5.0 means no `gitolite`. But it replacement, `gitlab-shell`, would deny any non git command, which explains why an `ls` would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the current [bug 3424](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3424)

You need to make sure:

- Gitlab application (with sidekiq consumers) and Redis has started
- the config is correct

Example of config issue:

> After relaxing a bit and reviewing all of my configuration files, I found my issue, which was my fault of course
>
> Without thinking while I was configuring my server, in the `/etc/hosts` file I added the name `x.m.com` to the loopback IP address (127.0.0.1).
>   Thus, any network calls performed on my local server to that name would go to that IP instead of the IP that NginX actually was bound to for the GitLab server.

Other example:

> I was able to resolve my issue by changing nginx configuration to listen to *:80 instead of specific IP. Apparently due to firewall different internal and external IPs.

```
listen *:80 default_server;
```

That last config error is discussed in details in [issues/3384](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3384#issuecomment-15457287).

---

The last release 5.1 helps, as the [OP Adam-E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558866/adam-e) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034293/gitlab-5-0-git-push-via-ssh-fails-but-no-errors-with-https-or-with-direct-ssh/16035322?noredirect=1#comment23155006_16035322), with the following steps:

> - swapped out Apache2 for nginx,
> - did a clean install of the just released GitLab 5.1 stable and
> - truncated `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` and
> - readded my public key.
>
> Since that last step it started working.

Comment: In my case, I'm running Apache with Passenger. It works fine and I didn't have this issue with another GitLab + Passenger installation. Not sure what's different in this case. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: @Adam-E I do use Apache with passenger myself: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitlab/apache.cnf.tpl But this bug was about the port you are listening in (Apache or NGiNX)

Comment: Nice project. I starred it. But why would the port number Apache is listening on not be an issue for cloning over HTTPS but is over SSH? For the record, I have `<VirtualHost *:443> ServerName git.server.com` in my site config.

Comment: @Adam-E mainly because the name of the server failed to resolved, while with a '*', there is no resolution issue: it listens for any name.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand now. Incidentally, the API is returning 404 for that ssh push action.

Comment: I swapped out Apache2 for nginx, did a clean install of the just released GitLab 5.1 stable and truncated `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` and readded my public key. Since that last step it started working.

Comment: @Adam-E Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.